# Exporting 3D objects with transparency

Tags: export

I use Blender 2.82, and I use the principled B.S.D.F.
How do I export a 3D object with transparent textures? Like glass and stuff.
Making the obj, fbx, and files like that.
The rest of it works fine, like the lights, the height, normal map, textures, etc.

I look in the 3D viewer, there's no transparent textures.

What nodes I'm using in Blender
[image]

How the image looks in Blender
[image]

How the image looks in the 3D viewer
[image]

Comment: You might want to tell us a little more about the purpose of that export. Otherwise nobody can give a definitive answer. Please read [**this**](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2620/could-we-brush-up-the-help-center-please) to learn how you could help us to give good answers.

Comment: I'm simply just trying to export my 3D model with the transparent textures. I've updated my question.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures/57541

Answer (score 1):

Use gltf/glb exporter to export with transparency .

The opacity alpha has to be in color image. (Check the documentation for correct export settings and node setup)

gltf format supports :

- Color + alpha
- Metallic + Roughness + AO
- Normal Map

all other maps will be ignored